# change or scale two normal distribution to have specific correlation coefficient

Tags: c++, algorithm, statistics

So, my question is, if we have two normally distributed random variables for instance if n1(8, 1) and n2(5, 1) have rho = 0.2
I want to change n1 and n2 in way to have rho = 0.8 or any other value.

how can do that in c++?
is there any library, package or algorithm to implement?

Any help or comments will greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Hi student_11, and welcome to the site. Some parts of your question aren't clear or are insufficiently specified. E.g. what is rho? What sorts of changes to the distributions are or aren't acceptable? What have you looked up or tried so far to work this out, so that answerers don't wind up repeating what you've already done? Also, what makes this a programming problem rather than a math problem? Changing the parameters of two normal distributions to make them have a specific correlation coefficient seems like a math problem, on the face of it.

Comment: Hi david, by rho i mean "correlation coefficient". my goal is to have random variables with specified rho. i a beginner programmer and i just need some tips to start with. i thought about changing the parameters too, but i dont know what is best way to do this? regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** I fixed equations.

If we suppose `x_1` and `x_2` are distributed in n1(8, 1) and n2(5, 1), respectively with correlation `rho`.
Then, using two independent n(0,1) variables `w_1` and `w_2`, we can write `x_1` and `x_2` as follows:

```
x_1 = w_1 + 8,
x_2 = sqrt(1 - rho^2) * w_2 + rho * w_1 + 5.
```

On the other hand, if we suppose `y_1` and `y_2` are distributed in n1(8, 1) and n2(5, 1) within correlation `rho'`, we can also write

```
y_1 = w_1 + 8,
y_2 = sqrt(1 - rho'^2) * w_2 + rho'* w_1 + 5.
```

Therefore, we can get new joint distribution with different correlation `rho'` by the following algorithm:

```
y_1 = x_1,
y_2 = sqrt((1 - rho'^2)/(1 - rho^2)) * (x_2 - rho * (x_1 - 8) - 5) + rho' * (x_1 - 8) + 5.
```

---

We can also directly generate `y_1` and `y_2` using [independent normal distribution (w_1 and w_2) generator in C++.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution)

Comment: thank you, Hiroki and Rubic. i think the Hiroki's approach more fits my problem.

Comment: Thx, my pleasure.

Comment: p1 = m1 + s1 * X
p2 = m2 + s2 * (rho X + sqrt(1 - rho^2) Y) i found this in statistics sites, is the sqrt() necessary for generating the distribution?

Comment: The key relations are <x_1> = <w_1> + 8 = 0 + 8 = 8, <(x_1 - 8)^2> = <(w_1)^2> = 1, <x_2> = sqrt(1 - rho^2) * <w_2> + rho * <w_1> + 5 = sqrt(1 - rho^2) * 0 + rho * 0 + 5 = 5,  <(x_2 - 5)^2> = (1 - rho^2) * <(w_2)^2> + rho * sqrt(1 - rho^2)  * <w_1 * w_2> + rho^2 * <(w_1)^2> = (1 - rho^2) * 1 + rho * sqrt(1 - rho^2)  * 0 + rho^2 * 1 = 1, and <x_1*x_2> = sqrt(1 - rho^2)  * <w_1 * w_2> + rho*<(w_1)^2> = sqrt(1 - rho^2)  * 0 + rho * 1 = rho.

Comment: could you please show me the reference of the equations you've posted above.thanks

Comment: Such a decomposition is applied frequently in analysis of correlated financial underlying assets. : (2.26) of https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:938934/FULLTEXT01.pdf , p.29 of https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/mcudina/Sections20_1_2_3 , http://www.bbk.ac.uk/ems/for_students/msc_finEng/pricing_emms014p/slecture3.pdf ,  https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/24472/two-correlated-brownian-motions , … .
Shreve’s book https://www.amazon.com/Stochastic-Calculus-Finance-II-Continuous-Time/dp/144192311X also describes this analysis in general case, I think.

Comment: one more question what if the initial rho == 1 then the y2 becomes undefined, or what if we want rho' = 1 , what should we do in these cases, thank you

Comment: If we want rho' == 1, y_1=x_1, y_2 = x_1 - 3.

Comment: If rho == 1, dimensional reduction occurs. Then the above transformation is failure and we need a direct y_1 and y_2 generator, I think.

Comment: if rho== 1, can we just adjust the sigmas to achieve the desired rho??

Comment: If rho == 1, x_1 and x_2 are not independent. Therefore converting (x_1, x_2, rho==1) into (y_1, y_2, rho'!=0) is impossible.

Comment: One possible approach is sampling x_1 twice, say x_11 and x_12. I believe that it's autocorrelation is very small and these variables are independent samples of n1(8,1). Then if we define w_1 := x_11 - 8, w_2 := x_12 - 8, w_1 and w_2 are independent samples of n(0,1). Thus we can again construct y_1 = w_1 + 8 = x_11 and y_2 = sqrt(1 - rho'^2) * w_2 + rho'* w_1 + 5 = sqrt(1 - rho'^2) * (x_12 - 8) + rho' * ( x_11 - 8 ).

Comment: @student_11 2  And an example of direct sampling of n(0,1) is here https://wandbox.org/permlink/B5peCd5MN5nsz9Aw .

Answer (score 1):

It's a 2 dimensional normal distribution with covariance matrix:

1,   0.2

0.2,  1

you can use MATLAB function "mvnrnd"

https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnrnd.html

I don't find any c++ libraries. Maybe you should implement it according to the method of mvnrnd.